# Can you restrict FCM senders by IP address? If so, how?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

In Google Cloud Messaging, one of the options available on the push API key was to restrict senders to specific IP addresses (whitelist). This allowed you to dedicate a group of push servers, and prevent machines with other IPs from sending pushes to GCM.

Does Firebase Cloud Messaging have the same or a similar option? I'm not able to find it, and it seems to have gone down the memory hole. If it has the option, how would you configure it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase Cloud Messaging REST API to send messages is open to all callers. The authorization options are described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server). As far as I know there is no direct way to limit usage of the API to specific IP addresses.

Comment: According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref it appears that old legacy server keys that have been migrated can still have IP restrictions, but no new legacy server keys may be created and "If you are using a legacy server key, you're recommended to upgrade to a new key that has no IP restrictions."